# Friction between tow objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUAKY.png)I need grip between two objects actually small cube is a player having rigid body and big cube is an object that helps small cube to jump on it and keep jumping on other big cubes to reach to the destination. I need when the player jumps and land on rotating cube so there should friction between them by default the player should rotate with big cube cause its on the big cube.

I checked rigid body Drag and Angular Drag.

The small cube having rigid body should also rotate with big cube cause big cube is rotating and small cube is on the big cube.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbKKC.png)

Comment: Sorry but can you ask one question that clears out what you exactly need help with?

Comment: @Skdy You can checkout my first question Grip between two object you may uderstand there what I am talking about by the given pictures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grip Between Two Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177723/grip-between-two-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use blend tree animations to achieve what you want. Without an sketch or a small Video it is difficult to figure out what the problem is. Sorry that I post here but I don't have enough Points.

Comment: You can checkout my first question Grip between two object you may uderstand there what I am talking about by the given pictures

Comment: Blend animation is something different.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create and add [Physics Materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) like shown on this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuUNnwswH94

Comment: you can checkout my first question Grip between two object you may uderstand there what I am talking about by the given pictures.

Comment: Physics Material does makes sence but still not working Physics Material is only using for how two objects will be contacting each other.